# Wort oder Redewendung für neu betrachtete Kindheitserinnerungen

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

Ich suche ein Wort oder Redewendung die folgende Situation bzw. Gefühl beschreibt:

*Wenn man zum Beispiel Jahre später in das frühere Haus/Dorf/... seiner Kindheit zurück kommt und alles sehr viel kleiner/trister erscheint als man es in Erinnerung hat.*

Falls es keine gängige Beschreibung dafür gibt, würden mich auch passende Wortneuschöpfungen interessieren.

Praktisch wäre auch ein Wort für das Gegenteil: Das einem als Kind alles größer/interessanter erscheint als später betrachtet.

Comment: Es wäre noch gut zu wissen, auf welcher Stilebene sich das Wort oder der Ausdruck bewegen sollte. Gepflegt-neutrale Sprache des Romans? Flappsiger Gassenjargon? Gewählt-latinisierte Ausdrucksweise der Literaturkritik?

Answer (score 6):

Ganz simpel und prosaisch (und vielleicht ein bisschen unspezifisch) könnte man von einem

> Realitätsschock

sprechen.

> Als ich nach Jahren in das Dorf meiner Jugend zurück kam, erlebte ich einen Realitätsschock. Der Hühnerstall war nicht halb so groß, wie ich ihn mir in der Erinnerung ausgemalt hatte, und die Kühe, unter denen ich früher noch hindurchlaufen konnte, reichten mir gerade mal so zur Brust.

Etwas unbefriedigend finde ich selber allerdings, dass "Schock" das Gefühl vermutlich zu sehr dramatisiert. Hm...

Answer (score 4):

Der Effekt, dass Erlebnisse oder die Umgebung aus lange zurückliegender Kindheit in der Erinnerung schöner erscheinen, wäre *Verklärung* [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verkl%C3%A4rung) [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verkl%C3%A4ren).
Den umgekehrten Effekt würde ich schlicht als *Ernüchterung* bezeichnen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann nur mit einer Wortneuschöpfung dienen und biete

> Nostalgiebremse

Dazu schreibt Wikipedia

> Nostalgie bezeichnet eine sehnsuchtsvolle Hinwendung zu vergangenen Gegenständen oder Praktiken.

Der Gedanken an die frühere Heimat lässt die Nostalgie aufflammen, die dann von der Realität jäh gebremst wird.

> Als ich nach Jahren in das Dorf meiner Jugend zurück kam, war es eine richtige Nostalgiebremse. Die charmanten Strandhäuschen sind modernen Hotels gewichen. Nichts sieht mehr so aus wie früher.

Für das Gegenteil erscheint mir Sinneswandel sehr passend.

> Als ich nach Jahren in das Dorf meiner Jugend zurückkam, erlebte ich einen richtigen Sinneswandel. Die langwelligen alten Bauten weiß ich im Gegensatz zu früher jetzt richtig zu schätzen.